# Issues with open PDF files from my server

Tags: reactjs, express, pdf, fs

Having issues with open/download a pdf coming from my backend (express). If I manually go to the endpoint in chrome (localhost:5000/test) it opens and displays the PDF as it should. Also works fine in postman if a choose "Save and download" in the client.

The response from the backend looks like below and from my understanding its a PDF stream? How can I view/download it from the frontend? I'm using React and Next.

```
%PDF-1.4
%����
1 0 obj
<</Creator (Chromium)
/Producer (Skia/PDF m79)
/CreationDate (D:20200127154327+00'00')
/ModDate (D:20200127154327+00'00')>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</ca 1
/BM /Normal>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Type /XObject
/Subtype /Image
/Width 135
/Height 23
/ColorSpace /DeviceRGB
/SMask 6 0 R
/BitsPerComponent 8
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 69>> stream
x���
 ���7
���:���7)AR��I �$%HJ�� )AR��I    �$%HJ���7`�˫��
endstream
endobj
6 0 obj
<</Type /XObject
/Subtype /Image
/Width 135
/Height 23
/ColorSpace /DeviceGray
/BitsPerComponent 8
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 51>> stream

..... a lot more like this
```

The PDF files are corrupted and it says Error - Failed to load PDF document when try to open them. I've tried convert it to a base64 string but getting the same error when open them.

Frontend function runs by onClick

```
   const config: AxiosOptions = {
      route: 'test',
      method: 'GET'
    };
    const res = await makeAxiosRequest(config);
    console.log('res', res.data);

    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href', 'data:"application/pdf;' + res.data);
    link.setAttribute('download', 'bp.pdf');

    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
```

Backend (express)

```
 const filename = __dirname + '/test.pdf';

    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
    const stat = fs.statSync(filename);

    res.setHeader('Content-Length', stat.size);
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
    res.setHeader(
      'Content-Disposition',
      'attachment; inline=test.pdf');

    // This will wait until we know the readable stream is actually valid before piping
    readStream.on('open', () => {
      // This just pipes the read stream to the response object (which goes to the client)
      readStream.pipe(res);
    });

    // This catches any errors that happen while creating the readable stream (usually invalid names)
    readStream.on('error', (err) => {
      res.end(err);
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out i needed to convert the pdf to a base64 string after all. 
Did this on the backend

```
 const filename = __dirname + '/test.pdf';
 const base64PDF = fs.readFileSync(filename, { encoding: 'base64' });
```

And then did this on the frontend

```
const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.setAttribute('href', 'data:"application/pdf;base64,' + res.data.base64PDF);
  link.setAttribute('download', res.data.name);

  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
```